# division of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I'm working on a problem involving division of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z_2}$. The question goes like this...

Find a greatest common divisor of the polynomials $x^6+x^4+x+1$ and $x^7+x^4+x^3+1$.

My textbook gave some examples but skipped a lot of the work and cannot follow what is going on. One example from the book said to find a greatest common divisor of $x^4+x^3+x+1$ and $x^5+x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z_2}$
. They got...

$x^5+x^2+x+1$ = $(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x+1)+(x^3+x)...$ and similarly
$x^4+x^3+x+1 = (x+1)(x^3+x)+(x^2+1)$.

How did they get this result? This should help clear things a bit before attempting the problem.

**EDIT**

I've attempted the original book problem and my gcd came out to $x^3+1$.

Comment: Euclidean algorithm, using long division of polynomials with remainder?

Comment: Yes but how does the result above occur? As I said, my textbook didn't go into details about the topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to typeset long division here, so I'll try to describe the procedure step-by-step instead. Say, we want to divide $x^5+x^2+x+1$ by $x^4+x^3+x+1$ with remainder over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Dividing the leading terms gives us $x^5/x^4=\color{magenta}{x}$ as the first term of the quotient. Now,
$$\color{magenta}{x}\cdot(x^4+x^3+x+1)=x^5+x^4+x^2+x,$$
and
$$(x^5+x^2+x+1)-(x^5+x^4+x^2+x)=-x^4+1=x^4+1,$$
the last equality being true because we're in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ where $-1=1$. Now we continue in the same fashion to divide the current polynomial $x^4+1$ by $x^4+x^3+x+1$. Dividing the leading terms gives us $x^4/x^4=\color{magenta}{1}$ as the next term of the quotient. Then,
$$\color{magenta}{1}\cdot(x^4+x^3+x+1)=x^4+x^3+x+1,$$
and
$$(x^4+1)-(x^4+x^3+x+1)=-x^3-x=x^3+x,$$
for the same reason. So we ended up with the quotient of $\color{magenta}{x+1}$ and the remainder of $\color{blue}{x^3+x}$.

Comment: Okay I sort of see it. So our gcd is $x^3+3$? By the way, I cannot upvote due to a low rep.

Comment: @jsmith300 That's fine, because I can upvote. This answer is brilliant, but the Euclidean algorithm says that you now have to repeat the procedure on the old divisor ($x^4+x^3+x+1$) and the new remainder ($x^3+x$). You keep doing this until the remainder of one of the divisions comes out to be zero. In that case, the last used divisor is the gcd. So repeat it and tell me what you get.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Thanks for the upvote and for the comment! My impression was that the OP's main challenge was the long division part, so I intentionally only demonstrated one example of division, not the whole Euclidean algorithm. I guess I should've stated that more clearly.

Comment: I do not know how to use colors but for the second case, I got $(x+1)$ as my quotient and $(x^2+1)$ as my remainder.

Comment: @jsmith300 Excellent. Now repeat the same procedure again: divide $x^3+x$ by $x^2+1$. I'll do it for you, this will give quotient $x$ and remainder zero. In this case, we see that the gcd of the given polynomials is $x^2+1$.

Comment: Ah so as you mentioned @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, the last used divisor is our gcd and it is indeed $x^2+1$.

Comment: @jsmith300 Exactly. I hope now, that you have understood the procedure of Euclidean division. If you want further clarification, then you can either edit the question or write a new answer for your original question, and then intimate me when you are done, so that I  can review it and tell you if you've got anything wrong.

Comment: I have actually finished the example in my book throughout our discussion and now I understand the concept of Euclidian division. As of now, I have no questions. I will attempt my original post and verify if it's correct or not.